# Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I want to pass data from client side to server-side. I am using jQuery and WebService. If data is small it works fine. If data is big it gives error. What I see in firebug Error is:

`Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug. ...`

So I know that data is too big, but it's my requirement. How can I handle this situation? Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this question:[Handling huge data via jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478149/handling-huge-data-via-jquery-ajax)

Basically Firebug has a limit of how much data is displayed in its panel. This has nothing to do with ASP.Net web service's max data size. That is controlled by the the following section in the web.config. This is for data passed from client to server and server back to client.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 17):

Go to Firefox's `about:config` page.

Search for the option named `extensions.firebug.netDisplayedPostBodyLimit`. Mine defaulted to 10240. Modify it to something large. The message will go away.