# Handling huge data via jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, firebug

I m building a blog in asp.net. I want to use jquery to add the posts and display them too. But I m not sure if it is gonna work fine in case of huge posts because last time I had problem posting a huge data using jquery ajax. The json object was truncated after 50000 characters by Firebug saying the

> Request Size Limit has been reached

I noticed for even for a normal post the number of characters cross 50K.
Is there a way to solve this "request size limit" or "is it a bad idea to pass such huge data using jquery". Please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using PHP? did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069342/xmlhttprequest-post-data-size

Comment: He is using ASP.NET. I have re-tagged the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try and set this setting in your web.config:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

More information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is a limitation of Firebug and NOT the Ajax request. Firebug has limits of how much data is shown in its network panel.

See this: [Firebug Preferences](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences)

This is the default:

**cache.responseLimit**
Maximum size limit for cached and displayed network responses
bytes    **5242880**